# Windows Home Server 2011 - Where has all my drivespace gone?

Tags: windows, windows-home-server

I have just installed Windows Home Server 2011 on a freshly built box with 2 x Samsung 2TB hard disks. Once the installation was complete I logged into the server and found that drive D: is reporting 1.75TB free (which seems right) but the C: drive only reports a total size of 60Gb!

Has anyone seen similar issues? Is this just WHS being clever with disk allocation?

Comment: Where are you checking the drive spacing? I'm thinking you might just have a bunch of unpartitioned space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2TB drive is seen by the computer as only having approximately 1860 GiB of raw space. This is due to the difference in counting it in binary (1KiB = 1024 B) in the OS versus decimal (1KB = 1000B) on the drive packaging.

1.75TB + 60 GB = 1810 GB, which is about right after losses from formatting, et cetera. This is for one drive, obviously.

Your drives are most likely being used in RAID 1 (mirrored drives), or you only formatted and partitioned a single drive.

Here's a decent explanation of the binary/decimal drive space issue: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/gigabyte-decimal-vs-binary.html

Comment: I'm being stupid, Windows has partitioned the primary HDD into two and ignored the second HDD. I've now formatted it and it appears as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

C drive is a dedicated system partition, typically 60 gb.  D drive is the rest of that disk. 
Next drive will be labelled E etc.